# Dual boot: ubuntu 20.04 doesn’t boot anymore

Tags: dual-boot

the only thing i can imagine that could cause this is: using ext2fsd to move some pictures from windows to ubuntu.

i’ve tried using `fsck` but just makes random numbers appear on screen

Answer (score 0):

Did you also do something like updating kernel or something?
Also, by 'not booting', you meant it loops back to grub , right?
in that case, try disabling secure boot from UEFI or BIOS.

Comment: it’s solved now, thanks for the help anyways, just had to repair the ubuntu filesystem